# How can I use describeBy with two groups?

Tags: aggregate, grouping, describe

I have two grouping variables, month and habitat for my dataset "chamber."  I am able to get the descriptive stats if my data is grouped by one variable, month OR habitat, but not both:

`describeBy(chamber,chamber$habitat)` or `describeBy(chamber,chamber$month)`

I've tried the following, but neither work:

```
describeBy(chamber,chamber$habitat+month)

describeBy(chamber, group="month"+group="habitat")
```

I can use aggregate to get just the mean by two groups: `aggregate(GCP~month+habitat,data=chamber, mean)` but not the other descriptive statistics such as the standard error.  GCP is one of several numerical variables in my dataset.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just found this code which seems to work!  Phew

```
describeBy(chamber, list(chamber$habitat, chamber$month))
```